# get only the node inside another one in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

Here's my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<book>
<title>My Title</title>
<description></description>
  <chapter>
    <title>Chapter 1</title>
    <description>text inside chapter</description>
  </chapter>
</book>
```

So I try to get information INSIDE the `<chapter>` tag

here's my code :

```
function afficheTitres(doc) {
  Items = doc.getElementsByTagName("chapter");
  elementol = document.createElement("ol");
  var longueur = Items.length;
  for ( k = 0; k &lt; longueur ; ++k) {
    elementli = document.createElement("li");

x=doc.getElementsByTagName("title")[k];
var longueurtitre = x.length;
y=x.childNodes[0];
txt=y.nodeValue;
test = document.createTextNode(txt)
elementli.appendChild( test);

    elementretour = document.createElement('br');
        elementli.appendChild( elementretour
    );

descript=doc.getElementsByTagName("description")[k];
descriptNode=descript.childNodes[0];
txt2=descriptNode.nodeValue;
test2 = document.createTextNode(txt2)
elementli.appendChild( test2);

    elementol.appendChild(elementli);
  }
  body = document.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0);
  body.appendChild(elementol);
}
```

The problem is that these lines :

```
x=doc.getElementsByTagName("title")[k];
```

and

```
descript=doc.getElementsByTagName("description")[k];
```

get information coming from the "BOOK" section not from the chapter.

I'm sure someone knows how to get this.

thanks

Comment: Why are you tagging it node js ?

Comment: @tomahim my thoughts exactly, I've removed it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm knew and I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you use `doc` variable which appears to be something inherited from `document` object, see [the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document).

The `.getElementsByTagName("title")` method returns an array of tags `title` which appears not just in the `chapter`, but also in the root element, `book`.

**Search from chapter node, not from doc**

```
var chapters = doc.getElementsByTagName("chapter");
for(var i=0; i<chapters.length; ++i) {

  // search from book, which is what you don't want
  // doc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];

  // search from chapter, you want this
  chapters[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
}
```

**Note**

In newer browsers (IE8+) you can save yourself lots of pain if you use `.querySelectorAll()` method (which btw renders great portion of jQuery obsolete).

```
var titles = doc.querySelectorAll("chapter title");
alert(titles[0].innerHTML); // Chapter 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting the collection of chapters first:

```
var chapters =doc.getElementsByTagName("chapter");
```

And then iterating through each chapter to find the child nodes of that instance in the collection?

```
if (chapters.length > 0)
{
   for (i = 0; i < resultList.length; i++) 
   {
      var title = chapters[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
      var desc = chapters[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0];

      // do work here
   }
}
```